# Android WebRTC on LAN: only candidate 127.0.0.1 is sent to signaling server

Tags: android, localhost, webrtc, lan, libjingle

I am trying to create an **Android video chat application based on WebRTC, for deployment on a local network**. The setup is simple: 2 Android terminals and one Linux server on the same local network (Ethernet). No STUN nor TURN server. Only host candidates, and a signaling server (HTTP+WS).

- A few years ago, I found [an Android app on GitHub](https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC), based on libjingle-9127, along with the associated Node.js server. It worked out of the box with my setup.
- This library being 4 years old, I tried to move to the [latest google-webrtc Android SDK](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/) + [a Node.js port of the appr.tc server](https://github.com/MidEndProject/node-apprtc). The signaling works well, but *the video chat itself fails*.

Trying to compare the two versions, I realized that the list of candidates sent to the signaling server is:

- one candidate per network interface with the libjingle version
- only 127.0.0.1 and :::1 with the google-webrtc version

This seems to be due to a mechanism of WebRTC called [Trickle ICE](https://support.frozenmountain.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/209706343-Why-sdp-Ip-from-method-OfferAnswer-is-127-0-0-1-local-IP-not-public-IP-) introduced in-between. And I don't know how to configure WebRTC to declare the candidates corresponding to my local network interfaces.

**Is there an API of the WebRTC Android SDK enabling me to do so?**

Thank you!

PS: The list of candidates sent to the signaling server.

**With libjingle-9127**

```
{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":0,"id":"audio","candidate":"candidate:2316705582 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.237.1 34869 typ host generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":1,"id":"video","candidate":"candidate:2316705582 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.237.1 34869 typ host generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":1,"id":"video","candidate":"candidate:2316705582 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.237.1 34869 typ host generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":0,"id":"audio","candidate":"candidate:3614478314 1 udp 2122194687 172.17.84.124 52163 typ host generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":1,"id":"video","candidate":"candidate:3614478314 1 udp 2122194687 172.17.84.124 52163 typ host generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":0,"id":"audio","candidate":"candidate:1846788752 1 udp 2122129151 172.17.116.134 45915 typ host generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":1,"id":"video","candidate":"candidate:1846788752 1 udp 2122129151 172.17.116.134 45915 typ host generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":0,"id":"audio","candidate":"candidate:13699457 1 udp 2122063615 10.11.239.176 51039 typ host generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":1,"id":"video","candidate":"candidate:13699457 1 udp 2122063615 10.11.239.176 51039 typ host generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":0,"id":"audio","candidate":"candidate:3298157534 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.237.1 36295 typ host tcptype passive generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":1,"id":"video","candidate":"candidate:3298157534 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.237.1 36295 typ host tcptype passive generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":0,"id":"audio","candidate":"candidate:2582868762 1 tcp 1518214911 172.17.84.124 44376 typ host tcptype passive generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":1,"id":"video","candidate":"candidate:2582868762 1 tcp 1518214911 172.17.84.124 44376 typ host tcptype passive generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]

,{"type":"candidate","payload":{"label":0,"id":"audio","candidate":"candidate:546324064 1 tcp 1518149375 172.17.116.134 41308 typ host tcptype passive generation 0"},"from":"-Dl0-BWMLUwmKvvcAAAD"}]
```

**With google-webrtc-1.0.26405**

```
03-15 18:29:47.008  2318  2347 D RoomRTCClient: GAE->C #1 : {"type":"candidate","label":0,"id":"0","candidate":"candidate:1510613869 1 udp 2121932543 127.0.0.1 58474 typ host generation 0 ufrag rhKZ network-id 4"}

03-15 18:29:47.009  2318  2347 D RoomRTCClient: GAE->C #2 : {"type":"candidate","label":0,"id":"0","candidate":"candidate:559267639 1 udp 2122005759 ::1 46169 typ host generation 0 ufrag rhKZ network-id 5"}
```

Comment: Actually, the problem does not seem related to _Trickle ICE_. When I look at the WebRTC traces, it seems that all UDP binds fail on the network interfaces that are not **lo**. I don't understand why, because I haven't changed the network configuration between my tests using **google-webrtc-1.0.+** and **libjingle-9127**. What is this mysterious error 101? See traces below.

Comment: `03-20 17:07:54.622 17423 19629 I basic_port_allocator.cc: (line 766): Allocate ports on 6 networks
03-20 17:07:54.622 17423 19629 W physical_socket_server.cc: (line 200): Binding socket to network address 10.
11.239.187 failed; result: -3
03-20 17:07:54.622 17423 19629 E basic_packet_socket_factory.cc: (line 53): UDP bind failed with error 101
03-20 17:07:54.622 17423 19629 W physical_socket_server.cc: (line 200): Binding socket to network address 172.17.116.154 failed; result: -3
03-20 17:07:54.622 17423 19629 E basic_packet_socket_factory.cc: (line 53): UDP bind failed with er (...)
`